# react-native-bootsplash fullscreen image

Tags: android, splash-screen

Any way to set fullscreen image (with complicated shapes) to splash screen to android (react-native)  instead background color and  icon centered on screen using react-native-bootsplash?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

android 12 and higher has limitations with build splash screen

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit more context to Oleksandr's answer. Android from version 12 onwards requires a single opaque color to be used for the background, meaning an image is unable to be used. It also requires the splash image to be a specific size and will clip larger images, so a fullscreen image will also not be a viable solution.

[Android Splash screen Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3lhq.png%7D)

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen